# Android submenu appears in place of main menu

Tags: android, android-menu

Are Android submenus supposed to just overwrite the main menu? I had hoped that the submenu would appear alongside the main manu item that was clicked, as in any desktop app (e.g. File/OpenRecent in Android Studio). But the original menu disappears when the submenu is shown:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "sub menu test");

    subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, 1001, Menu.NONE, "menu " + 1001);
    subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, 1002, Menu.NONE, "menu " + 1002);
    subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, 1003, Menu.NONE, "menu " + 1003);

    return true;
}
```

Can I change this action with code or by adding a style? (The submenu will be different each time so must be created, or at least edited, programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

> Are Android submenus supposed to just overwrite the main menu?

Yes.

> Can I change this action with code or by adding a style?

No, though you could create your own UI instead of using `Menu` and `SubMenu`.

> I had hoped that the submenu would appear alongside the main manu item that was clicked, as in any desktop app

Desktops, in general, have much larger screens than do most Android devices. They have the screen space to do that sort of fly-out behavior. Android's approach is designed to scale down to smaller screens. Any custom approach that you take will also need to consider how small of a screen you are willing to support.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the answer. Although with bigger screens these days and careful planning, a pop-out submenu should be easy enough. I did try a pop-up menu as well, but it's difficult finding an anchor, and the original menu still disappears when clicked.

Comment: @quilkin: "Although with bigger screens these days" -- bigger screens are a trend, not a guarantee. "a pop-out submenu should be easy enough" -- if I had to do one today, I would start with a custom [action provider](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views) and build out the UI from there. Jetpack Compose and Compose UI will probably offer easier flexibility here -- part of the problem is that `Menu` and `SubMenu` are ~15-year-old APIs at this point, and they are showing their age.

Comment: That sounds like quite a bit of work! It isn't esential for my app, I just thought it would look better. I'll leave it for now and hope that one day someone who's already written something will see my question !